# ffmpeg is it safe to do multiple audio filters simultaneously?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

So I have a few questions to go with this. I see a lot of people converting 5.1 to stereo by simply doing -ac 2... is this correct? I thought I would have to do something like:

```
pan=stereo|FL=FC+0.30*FL+0.30*BL|FR=FC+0.30*FR+0.30*BR
```

To properly downmix the audio. My other question is here is my encode I am doing:

```
    encodecmd = 'ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -stats -y -i "'+ filename +'" -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1 -map 0:0 -map 0:'+ audio +' -map 0:'+ subs + crop + ' -preset slow -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -pass 1 -af "compand=0|0:1|1:-70/-70|-60/-20|1/0:5:0:0:0" -c:a aac -b:a 160k -f matroska /dev/null && ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -stats -i "'+ filename +'" -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1 -map 0:0 -map 0:'+ audio +' -map 0:'+ subs + crop +' -preset slow -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -pass 2 -af "compand=0|0:1|1:-70/-70|-60/-20|1/0:5:0:0:0" -c:a aac -b:a 160k "'+ name +' ('+ year +').mkv"'
```

It's long yes, it's a 2 pass, but let me ask about the audio specifically, I want to do a compand compression with it. My understanding is compand runs over the entire audio file. so I don't think I can create stereo and do compand simultaneously.. I would have to encode the audio and downmix it first, THEN run compand?
Also is it bad to run compand on my first pass, since the audio doesn't need there? or does it have to be in the file that it generates..

```
-af "compand=0|0:1|1:-70/-70|-60/-20|1/0:5:0:0:0"
```

So to get to what I wonder: Do I have to downmix using my audio filter or do I only need -ac 2?
Am I able to combine compand and my pan=stereo downmix?
Do I need to have compand in my first pass of x264 or can I do it only in second?
I've tried these different ways for a few hours but I can't get it working, so I'm asking now.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Do I have to downmix using my audio filter or do I only need -ac 2?*

`-ac 2` implements FFmpeg's own stereo downmix, and unless you have specific needs, should prefer using it.

*Am I able to combine compand and my pan=stereo downmix?*

Yes.

`-af "pan=stereo|FL=FC+0.30*FL+0.30*BL|FR=FC+0.30*FR+0.30*BR,compand=0|0:1|1:-70/-70|-60/-20|1/0:5:0:0:0"`

*Do I need to have compand in my first pass of x264 or can I do it only in second?*

You can skip audio filtering in first pass. The only purpose of a first pass in a 2-pass process is to allow the video encoder to generate and store stats for the video stream.

---

Most filters, audio or video, process data one or a few frames at a time. The filters which require data from the whole stream, like `loudnorm`, do it in two passes, just like 2-pass video encoding.

Comment: Alright thanks, that answered all of it. It'll be a bit faster to take that out of the first pass. I'm familiar with loudnorm and kind of why I was wondering about the compand.  So I should, if I am doing random 5.1 sources, just use -ac 2 instead of my pan=stereo config?

Comment: Yes, default downmix should be acceptable for a random stream.

Comment: I wanted to add for anyone future googlers that -ac 2 is not the same as my pan=stereo config. you will find very terrible audio outcomes from converting a 5.1 or higher down to stereo when using -ac 2. Many sounds are meshed together unequally and some sections of movies are unbearable to listen to.